# How to use sort collection by tier price

Tags: magento

Just need to sort a product collection by tier price.

```
$collection->setOrder(’price’, ‘ASC’);
```

is working fine on my collection but `$collection->setOrder(’tier_price’, ‘ASC’);` is not working at all.

any hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 'tier_price' check this, whether its the accurate name being used by magento in db for tier price??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run something similar to the code below:

```
select attribute_id, entity_type_id, attribute_code 
from eav_attribute 
where attribute_code like '%tier%';
```

And then check which

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| attribute_id | entity_type_id | attribute_code |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
|           91 |              4 | tier_price     |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
```

The use the attribute_code as on your table.

```
$collection->setOrder(’tier_price’, ‘ASC’);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Medina, Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: After running the script I have got the same result as you. The attribute_code is tier_price. So I should use tier_price to sort the collection, but still $collection->setOrder(’tier_price’, ‘ASC’) is not working;